# Not allowed to load local - image from another machine

Tags: html, jsp

"Not allowed to load local" this is the error I get when I use developer console in the web browser.
When I copy paste this path name in my web browser it will display the image. BUT. When I try to put this file path in a HTML `img` or `href` it will still won't display.
This is my code I'm trying to use:

```
<a href="file://///machineName/foo/bar/image.jpg"  target="_blank">view image</a>

<img src="file://///machineName/foo/bar/image.jpg" width="100%" height="675px" alt="imagestuff" ID="imagestuff"/>
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. You aren't allowed to load that URL into your HTML document.

Comment: Your url is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is invalid. The syntax for local file, the hostname is omitted and the structure is

file:///c:/path/to/the%20file.txt  (yes, three slashes).
Check the file URI scheme : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme